# CSS problem with display flex and display block

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a class with the property `display: flex`. When I go to Chrome dev tools, it shows `display: block`, because of user-agent style sheet:

```
div { display: block; }
```

It seems I can't override it, even with `!important`. I have no other CSS class on this element.

If I use Bootstrap 4 `d-flex`, boom! It works.

Comment: Please include code in your question that replicates the behavior.

Comment: does it show `display: flex` crossed out?

Comment: Always provide a [mcve] so we can see what goes wrong

Comment: No surprises here. This is exactly how CSS works. Your class cannot affect the element unless the element has the class. A classless `div` will always be `display: block`, that is it's default.

Comment: Posting the whole code would be too large to post and for potential problem solver to debug (but thanks for

Answer (score 2):

I was simply hoping that someone would have experienced something like that and come up with a quick response. Posting the whole code would be too large to post and for potential problem solver to debug (but thanks to the person who voted me down without understanding that. Very appreciated). And I was not able to provide a smaller example where this behavior would be reproduced.
I finally solved it by re-designing my code, and it probably was a specificity problem.

Simram: The div had the class assigned to it.